# how to sort a list of words by the last character in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I wonder how to sort by the last character in bash? (The words have different length)

For example:

```
apple
birthday
Osaka
```

will be sorted to

```
Osaka
apple
birthday
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

You can use: `rev file.txt | sort | rev`

This will reverse words then sort based on the first character (actually last character in an unreversed way) and then reverse the output.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$ cat words.txt | sed -E 's/([a-z])$/:\1/' | sort -t: -k2,2 | tr -d ':'
Osaka
apple
birthday
```